# android extended LinearLayout, added XML with LayoutInflater, findViewById is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am creating a custom / extended LinearLayout which I am adding to a ViewAnimator obviously for cool effects.

So my main Activity has a ViewAnimator and I create an instance of this NavigationView I have been working on and add it to the ViewAnimator as a subview. The NavigationView itself uses LayoutInflater to grab the xml for the interface I made and attaches it to itself.

I then try to find this spinner which I know has the correct id and it always returns null. If I use this XML as the main content view of an Activity, I have no problem finding the spinner.

Here is my code:

```
  public class NavigationView extends LinearLayout {

    public NavigationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        addView(context);
    }

    public NavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addView(context);
    }

    public void addView(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav, this, true);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nav_spinner);
        if(spinner == null) Log.v("spinner", "null");

    } 
   }
```

So I always see "spinner" as "null" in the LogCat.

I see the interface I created added to the screen, but it's driving me nuts why it wont find this object by the id.

Could it be since it's inflated that it doesn't correctly assign ids?

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating you view at the wrong time. Remove the addView method, Override the onFinishInflate() method and do the inflation here. e.g

```
@Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
            super.onFinishInflate();
            ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav, this);

             Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nav_spinner);
             if(spinner == null) Log.v("spinner", "null");
    }
```

Comment: I have some code in the main activity which does the following: NavigationView navView = new NavigationView(this); viewSwap.addView(navView); I added a Log.v(...) in the onFinishInflate() of NavigationView but I'm not seeing it in the LogCat

Comment: ok, sorry i didn't notice you were not inflating this View from XML. You need to manually call this method where you were calling addView(). If that doesn't work, then you have an issue with one of your IDs

Answer (score 1):

So not sure why, given a few good suggestions and toying around with the code I ended up getting it to work:

```
public class NavigationView extends LinearLayout {

    public NavigationView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        this.init(context);

    }

    public void init(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav, this, true);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.navSpinner);
        if(spinner != null) {

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.nav_sections, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

It seems like the same exact code, maybe I just needed to clean my project after I took out the underscore?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call findViewById on the view you've inflated. So that means you need to try this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.nav_spinner);
```

Comment: I have tried that but it also returns null. So does the following: Activity a = (Activity) context; Spinner spinner = (Spinner) a.findViewById(R.id.nav_spinner);

Comment: hmmm, in that case, try renaming your nav_spinner to a different id name, I seem to remember that having a underscore in id's for widgets in the xml layout causes funny effects for android....once you rename it to an id with no underscores try what i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I took out the underscore but no success.

Comment: 1 more quick question, in your code are you importing android.R by any chance?

Comment: I am importing com.myapp.android.R. Otherwise I probably wouldn't see the layout from xml.

Comment: when you inflate the layout, i noticed that you use the method with 3 parameters, could you try using this one : inflate(R.layout.nav, null);